# Docusign Sender Notifications REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to set some of the senders notifications using json REST API and C# but it is not working, what am I doing wrong, I have:

```
{
"userSettings":[
{
"value":"false",
"name":"allowSendOnBehalfOf"
}
],
"signerEmailNotifications":{
"envelopeActivation":"false",
"envelopeComplete":"false",
"carbonCopyNotification":"false",
"certifiedDeliveryNotification":"false",
"envelopeDeclined":"false",
"envelopeVoided":"false",
"envelopeCorrected":"false",
"reassignedSigner":"false",
"purgeDocuments":"false",
"faxReceived":"false",
"documentMarkupActivation":"false",
"agentNotification":"false"
},
"senderEmailNotifications":{
"envelopeComplete":"false",
"senderEnvelopeDeclined":"false",
"withdrawnConsent":"false",
"recipientViewed":"false",
"deliveryFailed":"false"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have to set something in the `userSettings` node to set something in the following node `signerEmailNotifications`.

Select a setting that you don't want to mess with (such as enableDSPro, which is the retired version of the DocuSign Desktop Application).

The following will work for you

```
{ 
  "userSettings":[{
    'name':'canSendEnvelope',
    'value':null
  }],
  "signerEmailNotifications": {
    "envelopeActivation": false,
     "envelopeComplete": false
  },
  "senderEmailNotifications": {
    "envelopeComplete": false
  }
}
```

Comment: ok the signers are working fine now but if I use the senders notifications, it give me an error saying bad request, I have userSettings,signerEmailNotifications, senderEmailNotifications, userSettings and signerEmailNotifications but senderEmailNotifications does not, how come??

Comment: You have to include signerEmailNotifications first. I'll edit my answer

Comment: that does not work, userSettings and signerEmailNotifications do work but as soon as i add senderEmailNotifications, it does not work.

Comment: Post your call because my above example works for me perfectly.